# Inserting an empty map into Redis using HSET fails in Golang

Tags: go, redis

I have some code to insert a map into Redis using the `HSET` command:

```
prefix := "accounts|asdfas"
data := make(map[string]string)
if _, err := conn.Do("HSET", redis.Args{}.Add(prefix).AddFlat(data)...); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

If `data` has values in it then this will work but if `data` is empty then it will issue the following error:

> ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hset' command

It seems that this is the result of the `AddFlat` function converting the map to an interleaved list of keys and their associated values. It makes sense that this wouldn't work when the map is empty but I'm not sure how to do deal with it. I'd rather not add an empty value to map but that's about all I can think to do. Is there a way to handle this that's more inline with how things are supposed to be done on Redis?

Comment: The HSET command syntax is `HSET key field value [field value ...]`. One field and value is required.  Use an if statement to skip the command when the map is empty.

Comment: @BaytaDarell That's not really a solution here because I want the cache to contain the information that this key exists but has no data associated with it.

Comment: You cannot have an empty hash in Redis.  Add a dummy field.

Comment: So, I couldn't add an empty string to an empty string?

Comment: Use any field that will not be confused with or collide with regular application data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, Redis doesn't allow and never keeps an empty data structure around (there is one exception to this tho).

Here's an example:

```
> HSET members foo bar
(integer) 1

> EXISTS members
(integer) 1

> HDEL members foo
(integer) 1

> EXISTS members
(integer) 0
```

As a result if you want to keep your data structures around, you have to at least have one member inside them. You can add a dummy item inside the Hash
and ignore it in your application logic but it may not work well with other data structures like List.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the bucket of cold water.